# Subsetting, and altering a vector in a pipe

Tags: r, pipe, tidyverse

Reproducible Example:

```
> foo <- rep("A",8) %>% .[c(2,4,8)] <- "D"
Error in rep("A", 8) %>% .[c(2, 4, 8)] <- "D" : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
> foo <- rep("A",8) %>% {.[c(2,4,8)] <- "D"}
> foo
[1] "D"

# Desired Result is a vector such as:
> A,D,A,D,A,A,A,D
```

Context: I generate a vector and want to alter a specific range of elements to be empty strings. I've attempted this wrapped in parentheses, but that doesn't seem to perform the behaviour I'm after. Any suggestions? - I feel like I'm possibly approaching this in the wrong way...

I'm attempting this within a single pipe, I could do it in two lines with a subset as one of the answers below, but I feel this should be achievable, and that I've just possibly missed something relatively simple.

Comment: `... %>% replace(c(2,4,8), "D")`

Comment: @rawr - Exactly it. I knew it was something simple! If you move this to an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Another (admittedly much more convoluted) option using `purrr` : `foo <- rep("A",8) %>% modify_at(c(2,3,8), ~ "D") %>% as_vector`

Comment: Also working: `rep("A", 8) %>% `[<-`(c(2, 4, 8), "D")` or in `magrittr` verbs: `library(magrittr); rep("A", 8) %>% inset(c(2, 4, 8), "D")`

Comment: @markus your solution seems to not play well with markdown backticks -  
`rep("A", 8) %>% \`[<-\`(c(2, 4, 8), "D")`
Furthermore, can you explain how `\`[<-\`` works / is interpreted?

Comment: @A_Skelton73 you're right. Didn't notice it. When you do something like `x[5] <- "foo"`, where `x` is some character vector, the function that you're using is:  `"[<-"` (how do you escape the backticks?). This however is a non-standard function name, that's why it needs to be quoted. You can read more about it here: [cran.r-project.org](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Operators) and: [adv-r.had.co.nz](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#all-calls). `magrittr::inset` is just an alias, see `?inset`

Comment: @markus thanks for the links, I'll have a read. \\` will escape the backtick. - \``rep("A", 8) %>% \\`[<-\\`(c(2, 4, 8), "D")\``